# How to know device type of an android

Tags: android, screen-size, television

How can I know the device type between tablet, phone and tv box android ?
I already tried screen size with javascript but some tablet have the same screen size as a tv.

Comment: How did you tried with javascript ?

Comment: What difference does it make if the device is a "phone", a "tablet", or a "tv box"? After all, those are marketing terms more than technical ones. What are the technical differences between these categories that concern you?

Comment: To answer your question literally you can check the specific device manufacturer and model with this two different lines of code.

    android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
    android.os.Build.MODEL

This way you will know the device type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check is Tablet device.

```
private static boolean isTabletDevice(Context activityContext) {
boolean device_large = ((activityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);

if (device_large) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Activity activity = (Activity) activityContext;
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
            || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH
            || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM
            || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV
            || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
        AppInstance.getLogger().logD("DeviceHelper","IsTabletDevice-True");
        return true;
    }
}
AppInstance.getLogger().logD("DeviceHelper","IsTabletDevice-False");
return false;
```

}

Check is Android Tv

```
public static final String TAG = "DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck";

UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device")
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device")
```

}